# Hosting a simple script with user inputs on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I am a beginner in python, and am trying to host my python script on PythonAnywhere, just for fun. I took my code from a Codecadamy exercise to make a Python piglatin translator, which requires user inputs. I am having trouble getting it to host the actual application part. Here is my current code.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app=Flask(__name__)

#main page
@app.route("/")
    def translate():
    return "Welcome to Nathan's Pyglatin Translator!"
    word1= input("Enter your word:")
    pyg="ay"
    word2=word1.lower()[1:len(word1)]
    word1=word1.lower()
    if len(word1)>1 and word1.isalpha():
            if word1[0]=="a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u" or "y":
                print(word1+" ---->"+word2+"-"+word1[0]+pyg)
            else:
                print(word1+" ---->"+word2+"-"+word1[0]+pyg)
    else:    
        print("Please enter a word longer than 1 character, without numbers.")
    print(" ")
    print("--Note that this doesn't work well with words that begin with a vowel--")
    print("Suggestions? Comments? Contact me.")

if __name__=="__main__":
port=int(os.environ.get('PORT',5000))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=port)
```

I'm able to get the code run perfectly (without the Flask code related to hosting it on the web page) in Spyder or Jupyter Notebook, but when I try to host it as is on PythonAnywhere it only shows "Welcome to Nathan's Pyglatin Translator!"

What is the easiest, least-complex way of getting it to actually prompt the user for their word and then go through the script and print the new word on screen? Hopefully it's just a small thing I'm missing.

Comment: The thing there is that you are running a script that is console based and not web. In order to use inputs in web you need to use a form in your page or run an API service to which you communicate through something like postman or curl in your console. Also, when you use return the function terminates so the rest of your script isn't even running

Comment: That makes sense, and I figured it would be something like that. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, what would be the best way to do this if I'm trying to present it to a third party user? Should I try to find a Python console API for html, or is there still a way to do it in Python? What is the best way to make it so that all the user does it type one word into one text box and the website/code does all the rest?

Is this way over my head? Is Python even what I should be using for this?

Comment: There are ways to embed "consoles" but that is way more difficult than you may think. I would believe that the best way would be to present a form that asks for a word to translate and then that request is sent to your service which translates it and shows the translated word.

Answer (score 4):

PythonAnywhere admin here.  There are two possible solutions here.

- the first way keeps your code running in a console.  To be able to share interactive consoles with anonymous strangers, we have a feature called [gist consoles](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/gists/).  To get that working, you'd have to upload your code to a github gist, and then copy the gist url to the pythonanywhere gist consoles service.  Then you'll get a URL that will allow anyone on the internet to get their own console running your code
- the second way involves changing your code to being a web application.  You would use HTML to display a form allowing the user to submit their inputs, and also to display the results.  On the server side, you would use Python to process their request.  My colleague Giles wrote [a basic guide to use Flask on PythonAnywhere](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/121/).  That actually does slightly more than what you want (you wouldn't need the database part), but if you follow it, you'll learn about how to create HTML pages and process form data...